# Inner Product of Formal Lie Algebra Characters?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The inner product of characters of a compact Lie group is defined by integrating over the group.

Question: Is it also possible to compute the inner product combinatorially from the formal characters?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Formally it's determined by the fact that the characters of irreps form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: But I suppose you need to already know the characters of the irreps (i.e., the Weyl Character Formula) to make this practical?

Comment: @Drew: you can also try to extract some information from the Weyl integral formula.